# SQL Server - DISTINCT on one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have a query where I join 3 relations....A, B &. The join is on a unique id. Table B contains rows similar to each other and I want to do a DISTINCT on a FK column in table B (the PK from A).

To make this more clear:

```
    A              B           C
---------      ---------   ---------
No. (PK)       Id(PK)       Id (PK)
Name           Role         Address
               No.(FK)      No.(FK)
```

Table B can have multiple instances of people from table A. I want a query which pulls fields from A, B & C joined on the No. field. Table B can have several rows with the same value for the No. column, therefore I want to perform a DISTINCT on the No. column.

How can I do this?

**Example Data:**

```
NAME          ROLE       ADDRESS
---------------------------------------
John Smith    Manager    1, The Village
Dawn French   Secretary  2, The City
John Smith    SQL Dev    1, The Village
Terry Tibbs   HR Manager 8, The Road
```

This is an example of a join on relations A, B & C:

```
 SELECT A.Name, B.Role, C.Address 
 FROM A, B, C 
 WHERE A.No = B.No AND B.No = C.No
```

Table B could contain several John Smiths (the same person) who has multiple roles -> therefore I want to do a DISTINCT on the No. that uniquely identifies a person. This is th ePK of Table A (No.).

Comment: It's not clear whether this is a SQL or a LINQ(-To-Sql) question or whatever since you've tagged all(but not the dbms).

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is grouping.

Comment: Can you show the data you have and the data you except?

Comment: hi see edit - using sql server

Comment: You should use the standard ANSI JOIN syntax `FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.No = B.No INNER JOIN C ON B.No = C.No`

Comment: I thought `Distinct` is fixed to Distinct Rows. Even if you try it on a column, it will apply to the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to summarize your results using group by on the No, column.  The question is what do you want to do with different values in the other columns when the No. value is the same?

One solution might be:

```
select a.No, a.Name, 
b.MinRole, b.MaxRole, b.RoleCount,
c.Address
from a 
join (
  select b.No, Min(b.Role) as MinRole, Max(b.Role) as MaxRole, 
  Count(distinct b.Role) as RoleCount
  from b group by b.No
) as b on a.No = b.No
join c on a.No = c.No
```

This assume a.No is unique in a and a and c have a 1 to 1 on No

Comment: Well the truth is, all that matters is the name value and the no. value. everything else can be omitted as it wont be displayed in the select..

Comment: I think you are saying that there is a 1 to 1 between a and c, but a 1 to may between a and b. So for each no in a what do you want to show when there are multiple bees? Sql isn't too good about agregating strings into something like role1, role2,... so one option is to see the smallest roll, largest roll and count of roles. See revised answer, based on this.

Answer (score 0):

In you solutions one person may have multiple roles and multiple addresses. "One column DISTINCT" requires subquery trick (as other folk already showed you). But if your query is to show primary (or just one of many) role and primary address for every one person, your query may be much simpler.

```
SELECT
A.Name,
(SELECT TOP 1 Role FROM B WHERE B.No = A.No) AS PrimaryRole, -- you may add ORDER BY here
(SELECT TOP 1 Address FROM C WHERE C.No = A.No) AS PrimaryAddress, -- add ORDER BY
FROM A
ORDER BY A.Name
```