# SQL Query Removing Duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008

So A quick question about an SQL query,

I have a table containing VendorNames, VendorCity and VendorStates. I would like to pull these 3 columns but only return one result per city and state. In other words I would like the query to return results where a vendor does not have a city and state in common with another vendor.

The table name is Vendors and the column names above are correct.

Comment: I think you're asking two things here: One result per city/state is not the same as a query for vendors that do not have a city and state in common with another vendor. For the latter, you could group by city, state and select city, state, max(VendorName) where count(VendorName) = 1. For the former, you'll need the tricks found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143210/sql-server-distinct-on-one-column

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT VendorCity, VendorStates, min(VendorNames)
FROM Vendors
GROUP BY VendorCity, VendorStates
HAVING count(VendorNames) = 1
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly, I see I was making it too complicated. I made this more like the SQL that Jyparask posted, and I could not get it to work.

Thank you for this!

Comment: @DanielErb Accept this (and other answers in other questions) as your accepted answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT V.* 
FROM VendorTable V
     JOIN 
     (
         SELECT VendorCity, 
             VendorStates,
             Count(*) AS NoOfVendorNames
         FROM VendorTable
         GROUP BY VendorCity,
                  VendorStates
     ) T
     ON V.VendorCity = T.VendorCity
         AND V.VendorStates = T.VendorStates
WHERE  T.NoOfVendorNames = 1
```